# AngularJS service dependency injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head></head>
<head>

</head>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" class="{{$state.current.data.specialClass}}" landing-scrollspy id="page-top">

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/myService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an angularJS app which was working fine before adding a service.
I am getting the following error. 
myService.js:3 Uncaught Reference    Error: myApp is not defined
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?
I am tying all the controllers to the module. I have also added the myService file to the index.html
Below is the code that I have in controller:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, myService){
};

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .controller('FinalViewCtrl', FinalViewCtrl);
```

```js
This is what I have in myService.js
    'use strict';
    myApp.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
    }]);
```

Let me know if I am missing anything?

Comment: The problem seems to be your controller, you are trying to inject service in your controller before you have declared it. Move myservice.js before controller.js  in script declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the myapp variable initiation just above the service code.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp');
   myApp.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
    }]);
```

Comment: I am still getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] even though the first error is gone.

Comment: angular.js:13236 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:38
    at sb (angular.js:1825)
    at Sa (angular.js:1835)
    at angular.js:9831
    at A (angular.js:8852)
    at u (angular.js:8898)
    at g (angular.js:8226)
    at g (angular.js:8229)
    at angular.js:8106
    at angular.js:1696

Comment: @sai123. Seems the error is related the controller loading. Move your controller function underneath the following statement. angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .controller('FinalViewCtrl', FinalViewCtrl);

Comment: @sai123: Seems the error is related the controller loading. Since you are using the controller in Body you need to move all <script> references under the <body> tag to <head> tag of the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Without the html, it will be hard to tell, but are you adding your JavaScript files in the correct order? You have to make sure that your file with `angular.module('myApp')` is loaded before any controllers or services. I've had the same error you have when adding my service before my app.